# Wear emulator shows handheld activity launcher class

Tags: android, emulation, wear-os, handhelddevice

I am trying to sync Mobile handheld device to android wear, connection was done successfully but when comes to wear emulator it launches handheld main activity

My handheld manifest file:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" ></category>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

my wear manifest manifest file

```
  <activity
        android:name=".WearActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" ></category>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What am i forgetting or something missing
help me out 
thnx in advance for help

Comment: hello this solve?

Comment: yes i solved this, thnx

Comment: ohk very good keep it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It will show handheld device's MainActivity in Watch because you have installed handheld device's apk in Watch. You have to change module from app to wearable for installing like,

Use following module to install,

[image]

Instead of following one,

[image]